# New install Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't boot after apt upgrade

Tags: boot, system-installation, kernel

On a new HP Omen 017 (Nvidia RTX 4090) installed the Ubuntu 20.04.2 I had handy. Dual boot with W11.

First thing after login

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dkpm
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Restart will not boot

Updated the BIOS to latest

The only way I can boot is with Advanced Ubuntu Options, and select the previous kernel, 5.8.0-43-generic, but I can't boot with kernel 5.15.0-79-generic.

Thanks for the help!

DBG

Comment: Why did you use 20.04.2 media?  5.8 is no longer a supported kernel, with 5.15 being the *supported* HWE kernel. I don't know what [dkpm](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=dkpm&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) is, nor what sources you added to install it given that isn't a Ubuntu package.

Comment: I have a Thinkpad L590 and I also get issues suddently. I could not boot today, I had to enter in Grub "Advanced options" to boot, and select the kernel 5.15.0-78 to get a valid boot, somehow the newer 5.15.0-79 that got installed during an update since the previous boot and is selected automatically by grub by default cannot boot. Can it be the same problem? In this case, this is not limited to the more modern hardware of @Dave ?

Comment: Ie for now I solved this by booting in advanced mode and selecting the older kernel version as you do too.