# Problem with boot after update 22.04 Desktop

Tags: boot, updates, 22.04, amd-processor

Booting crash after updating 22.04 to last packages. CPU AMD Phenom. Text console boot possible (rescue mode).

Comment: Can this be the same issue as https://askubuntu.com/questions/1483141/new-install-ubuntu-20-04-doesnt-boot-after-apt-upgrade#comment2597532_1483141 ? I also have the same issue. Solved for now by booting in advance mode and selecting the previous kernel version.